# Create new table from multiple existing tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I am trying to create a new table from multiple existing tables in SQL Server. The "CREATE TABLE AS" Clause gives me an error, the "INTO" Clause works for me. However the new table result do not update as the data changes in the original tables. Is there a way to create a new table that shows updated results.

This is the syntax used

```
SELECT 
    ST.StockID, SH.ShopID, SB.Barcode, SS.SupplierCode, ST.Description, 
    ST.FamilyClassID, FC.Description AS FC_Description, ST.TaxRate, 
    ST.RRP, ST.BusinessPrice, ST.SalePrice, ST.SaleBusinessDateFrom, 
    ST.SaleBusinessDateTo, ST.Inactive, SH.OnHandNonInt, ST.LastModifiedDT
INTO 
    W_Prod_Sync
FROM
    [dbo].[Stock] AS ST
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[StockBarcode] AS SB ON ST.StockID = SB.StockID 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[StockOnHand] AS SH ON ST.STOCKID = SH.STOCKID
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[FamilyClass] AS FC ON ST.FamilyClassID = FC.FamilyClassID
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[StockSupplierCode] AS SS ON ST.StockID = SS.StockID
ORDER BY 
    ST.Inactive ASC, ST.LastModifiedDT DESC
```

Comment: I think you wanted a [VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: There is not such thing as a table which is automatically synced to another table. Maybe you could provide more context for what you are trying to do.

Comment: The only option that creates something like an "auto-update table" would be an **indexed view** in SQL Server - [see this doc for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16) - but the list of requirements that the SQL code for creating the view needs to meet is quite long - so in many cases, it's not feasible....